# How to remove or change the Coupling-Map limit is qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, transpile

I am trying to implement large qiskit circuits which give coupling map error as coupling map cannot exceed 31 is basic `aer_simulator` or even `statevector_simulator`.

So, I want to increase the limit or use a simulator with high number of coupling map preferably 100.